# Show that $\bar Y = \bar X$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ exists such that it is a  subset of the real line, and let $Y$ be a set and $X\subseteq Y\subseteq \bar X$. Show that $\bar Y = \bar X$

### My Attempt

What I know

$\bar{X}$ = adherent points of $X$.

$\bar{Y}$ = adherent points of $Y$.

$X\subseteq \bar{X}$.

$Y\subseteq \bar{Y}$.

So if $X\subseteq Y$ then $\bar{X} \subseteq \bar{Y}$.

Comment: $X \subseteq Y \subseteq X$ is equivalent to $X=Y$, from which the claim trivially follows. Are you sure you have the question right?

Comment: There was a typo, I edited it

Answer (score 0):

You say "if $X\subseteq Y$ then $\bar{X} \subseteq \bar{Y}$".

So by assumption above  $X\subseteq Y \subseteq X$), you also have $Y \subseteq X$, and hence $\bar{Y} \subseteq \bar{X}$. So you've shown containment both ways.

Comment: There was a typo so I had to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm guessing the question is with $X \subseteq Y \subseteq \bar X $)

Since $X \subseteq Y$, $\bar X \subseteq \bar Y  $

Since $Y \subseteq \bar X  $, $\bar Y \subseteq \bar{ \bar X} = \bar X $

Rq : To prove that  $X \subseteq Y$ implies $\bar X \subseteq \bar Y  $, note that a limit of a convergent series of $X$ is also a limit of a convergent series of $Y$

Comment: Yes, you are correct, i edited the question,. Sorry for the typo

Comment: How does this show that $\bar Y = \bar X$ ?

Comment: $\bar X \subseteq \bar Y$ and $\bar Y \subseteq \bar X $ means $\bar X = \bar Y $

Comment: Can I actually prove this problem using definition only? Maybe I can prove that  prove $\bar{Y}$ is contained in $\bar{X}$. i.e. given  $z$ in $\bar{Y}$. you  for every $\epsilon$, you need to find an element $x$ in $X$ such that $|x-z|\leq \epsilon$. Since $z$ in $\bar{Y}$, you can find a $y$ in $Y$ such that $|z-y|\leq 1/2\epsilon$, since $y$ lies in $\bar{X}$. you can find a $x$ in $X$ such that $|x-y|\leq 1/2\epsilon$. Am I right? What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, your proof is also correct, you just need to finish it using the triangle inequality

Comment: can you should me how to use the triangle inequality to finish this?

Comment: $\epsilon \leq (\epsilon/2) + (\epsilon/2)?$